# Setting the rotation to a mix of localRotation and world Rotation in Unity 5 (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions, euler-angles

I'm trying to set a child gameObject equal a mix of the localRotation of the root and 0's of the world.

(This gameObject is a gun of sorts that the player character holds, like a fireflower, and out of the face of this object fireballs are released)

Essentially I want this item to always face forwards (so it faces towards where my character is facing). When I do:

```
this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,0);
```

the X and Z are correct, but the Y value always stays facing the same forward direction no matter where the character rotates.

I've messed around and found that

```
this.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (270, 180, 90);
```

works slightly, but it is off by an amount that would require me to do a lot of trial and error with and I would rather work with non hardcoded values.

In the end I want to have a localRotation equal to (0 of World, parentRotationY, 0 of World), but I can't get it to work.

So is there any way to mix a localRotation and a world rotation?

Also if I'm not providing enough information just let me know.

Comment: Is it necessary to perform this rotation strictly through direct calculation, or can you use a method that abstracts away most of that, like `LookAt()`?

Comment: @Serlite it needs to be stricly calculated, because the lookat would not allow me to have the strict 0 x and 0 z.

Comment: So, the gun is always attached to your character and you want it's rotation to always face forward to the character? If so gun.rotation = character.rotation.

Comment: Yes, but I want to zero out the x and z values, the only value I want the same as the character, is Y.

Comment: Can we see a screenshot of your hierarchy, maybe a mockup of what the rotation values should look like if applied by code?